# git read-tree removed all the history

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-merge

I'm trying to merge two repos using `git read-tree`.
The problem is, the previous commit history of merged files disappeared. I did check file by file obviously.

I followed normal way of doing subtree merging based on this article:
[6.7 Git Tools - Subtree Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging)

```
$ git remote add rack_remote git@github.com:schacon/rack.git
$ git fetch rack_remote
$ git checkout -b rack_branch rack_remote/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=rack/ -u rack_branch
```

My current workspace structure looks like:

```
project P
   - repoA
   - repoB
   - repoC
   (... and many more repos)
```

And I wanna change the hierarchy of them and to be like:

```
project P
   - repoA <=== have repoB and repoC inside.
```

**I could't see merged files' history on the example above and mines too on `git log` result.**
(I wanna underline my repos are svn cloned ones still linked to the svn repository. Could this affect read-tree behavior?)

EDIT: I tried with original Github repos and the problem was the same.

Comment: do the two repos share a common ancestor? if so, why do you need a tree-merge?

Comment: @mb21 what do you mean by ancestor? they're in the project, but separate repos. i wanna restructure projects, moving all including history.

Comment: @honey, a "common ancestor" would be a commit that exists in both repositories, likely early in the history, e.g. as would exist if the two repos originally started as one. It sounds like the answer is no.

Comment: @Chris I see. nope :)

Comment: `read-tree` just reads a snapshot into working copy, it is not aware about a history.

Comment: @kan every documents say `read-tree` makes history remained, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The steps you described do not add the merged history as a second parent. From the text in the link it seems like that was their intention. Since you intention is different, you should modify the commands a bit:

```
$ git remote add rack_remote git@github.com:schacon/rack.git
$ git fetch rack_remote
```

Now, first initiate a merge. The command uses "ours" strategy, so it does not really change anything yet.

```
$ git merge -sours --no-commit rack_remote/master
```

Then modify the content:

```
$ git read-tree --prefix=rack/ -u rack_remote/master
```

And finally commit (will spawn editor):

```
$ git commit
```

Now it's done: you have the merged files in subdirectory and their history.

This is probably not the only way to create merge commit with arbitrary content but the first one which worked for me. Note also that there is no need to create a local branch mirroring `rack_remote/master`, you can use the remote reference.

PS: you will need to use --follow to track the file histories, because the merge renamed them.

Comment: I exactly followed the every step, and skipped some of them above though. Thanks for '--follow' anyways. It looks like github does not use this option to show a file's history.

Answer (score 3):

You could just merge two repos into one. I.e.

```
git clone repoB
cd repoB
mkdir b_proj_dir
git mv * b_proj_dir/
git commit -m "move b to subfolder"

cd ..
git clone repoA
cd repoA
git fetch ../repoB
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: This was by FAR the easiest approach for me.  I suspect many who have gone down this road are mystified when they think their git log history disappears, when in fact it's still there but they failed to use the --follow option to see history prior to moving repoB contents to a subdirectory.  After cloning my source repo from SVN with git svn into repoB, then moving to my desired subdir for that project, I did the above to merge into my ultimate host, repoA.  The actual manipulations took only a couple of minutes.  Only tweak: must add "--allow-unrelated-histories" option to final git merge.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories". Any ideas

Comment: Ah, `--allow-unrelated-histories` obviously!